# Rendering ajax result in different view Rails 3

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Given that I have the **routes**.

```
  root :to => 'pessoas#index'
  post '/pessoas'  => 'pessoas#create'
```

And my view app/view/pessoas/**index.haml** has the following view code. (Submit here will post to pessoas#create)

```
= form_tag "/pessoas", :method => :post, :remote => true, :id => "participe" do
  ...
  = button_tag "Sign up", :class => "envia"
```

And my **create.js.erb** view is.

```
$('#user-feedback').html('<%= @message %>');
```

And the controller code simply saves the model.

```
  def create
    @pessoa = Pessoa.new(params[:cliente])
    if @pessoa.save
      @message = "Success"
    else
      @message = "Failure"
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Then I go to the root path /
And I fill the form and click on submit. 
Then the element p#user-feedback haven't been changed. Why?

I notice in app's log: that the request was done right and the jquery also but it render at /pessoas response but not at current view (index).

What can I do? Or should I just forget about this and make this with $.ajax way?
I want a way to provide feedback to the users.

Comment: You might try adding `:format => :js` on the form_tag and/or use `escape_javascript(@message)` in place of `@message`.

Comment: Actually it does the request and it saves the model and it returns a valid html with name pessoas but I would like to change my current view only that is on #index action.